# Where should I put the transitioning from tile to laminate with open floor plan?

Tags: floor

I have an open floor plan in my house. The house is about 25 years old and the same white glossy tile was used in the living room, dining room and large kitchen. The tile looks decent in the living room and dining room. The kitchen tile looks awful. the grout was painted with regular paint by the previous owner and it looks terrible and is impossible to keep clean. I would like to replace the kitchen only with a good laminate. My problem is where to transition from kitchen. I am not sure where the cut off should be and will it look ok. can I send some pictures? I would like it to look like it has always been this way.

Comment: Some photos would help, but honestly it's likely more dependant on personal preference.

Comment: Laminate does not take water particularly well - as such, the kitchen may not be the best place for laminate. If the appearance problem in the kitchen is the grout, use a grout saw to remove the paint and grout, and re-grout it. Then seal it for easier cleaning.